# The specified value "IN072" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

I am trying to auto fill an entry in my django template using the code below:

```
    var pq1 = document.getElementById("q1").textContent;
    var p1 = document.getElementById("p1").textContent;
    document.getElementById("id_product1_quantity").value = (Math.ceil(x / r) * pq1);
    document.getElementById("id_product1").value = p1;
```

Where id_product1_quantity gets filled correctly but id_product1 throws the following error:

> The specified value "IN072" is not a valid number. The value must
>   match to the following regular expression:
>   -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

How can I solve this and why is this occuring ?

Comment: You need to pass a valid number. IN072 is not a number. You can solve this by using a Regex expression to get only the number from the string, or change the way your input works.

Comment: @GlennvanAcker Actually p1 consists of a string, how can I pass the string into `id_product1`?

Comment: what does that element look like? is it an input field for numbers? then you have to parse it to a number. if it is for a string, then there should be no problem to begin with.

Comment: My mistake, I accidentally made it an input field for numbers.. changed it to characters and now it works